# drawing svg:circle on d3.svg.area().interpolate("basis")

Tags: javascript, charts, svg, protovis, d3.js

Here is my Code on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gDq3/1/) I am using `d3.svg.area()` to draw an area and drawing the points as `svg:circle` on it. whch works okay If I change `.interpolate('basis')` to `.interpolate('cardinal')` or `linear` But how to put the points properly with `basis` interpolation ? e.g. I want to put the `near match` points

Comment: I too have this problem. Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interpolation method "monotone" that will respect your y maximum and therefore your circles will not be displaced.
-Canimus

Comment: I don't want the line to be drawn over the circles. rather I want the circles to be drawn where the curve and y axis meets.