# D3 - Difference between basis and linear interpolation in SVG line

Tags: svg, charts, d3.js

I implemented a multi-series line chart like the one given [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) by M. Bostock and ran into a curious issue which I cannot explain myself. When I choose linear interpolation and set my scales and axis everything is correct and values are well-aligned.
[image: Linear interpolation]

But when I change my interpolation to basis, without any modification of my axis and scales, values between the lines and the axis are incorrect.

[image: Basis interpolation]

What is happening here? With the monotone setting I can achieve pretty much the same effect as the basis interpolation but without the syncing problem between lines and axis. Still I would like to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The basis interpolation is implementing a [beta spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline), which people like to use as an interpolation function precisely because it smooths out extreme peaks. This is useful when you are modeling something you expect to vary smoothly but only have sharp, infrequently sampled data. A consequence of this is that resulting line will not connect all data points, changing the appearance of extreme values.

In your case, the sharp peaks are the interesting features, the exception to the typically 0 baseline value. When you use a spline interpolation, you are smoothing over these peaks.

Here is a fun demo to play with the different types of line interpoations:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190

You can drag the data around so they resemble a sharp peak like yours, even click to add new points. Then, switch to a basis interpolation and watch the peak get averaged out.

[image: Basis interpolation]

Comment: Completely agree with that, not really what I asked though. Yes linear interpolation is clearer for this chart but I'm asking anyway since I may run into the same problem later (in fact I already have).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought the question was why do your values look different with a basis interpolation. What are you asking?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear :) The two pictures I uploaded were generated with the same dataset. For example, the max value in my dataset is 100. In the linear interpolation the axis shows that correctly, as the peak has y value 100 according to the axis. But then I change to basis interpolation and now my highest value (according to the axis) is around 70, while it is not the case. It's as if the domain of my scale had changed, except it hasn't because all I did was change the interpolation parameter. I was wondering why this happened and what I could to to prevent it.

Comment: That's precisely what I thought the question was, and I am sorry that I was obviously not clear enough. The purpose of the basis interpolation is so that the peaks' maximum (or minimum) values will regress towards the mean. The peaks should look different, as that is what the basis interpolation is designed to do. Take a look at the picture I added to my answer from the demo I linked. The peak data point is far higher than the peak of the curve when using a basis interpolation, because the basis interpolation smooths out peaks.

Comment: Oh okay I just understood. In my mind the basis interpolation HAD to pass through my data points, like the point where y = 100, in a similar manner to the Lagrange polynomials for example. But that's just not the case, investigating the math behind and giving your linked example another try made me realize. Thank you for your input !

Comment: Edit: Your previous comment just beat this one to the punch- that was the piece of info I forgot, to mention that the interpolation does not have to touch all the data. The spline interpolation will not connect all data points, but only draw a smooth line through them constrained by the first and last points. To avoid having the actual heights of your curves change, use an interpolation that is constrained to physically touch all the data points, like monotone as you suggested. Happy interpolating!