# Draw a circle at a point on an NVD3 line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

how to draw a circle on a peak point in line chart nvd3 
e.x:

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    ;

  chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))
    ;

  chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
    ;

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data())
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart)
    ;

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

this is an example of line chart and i want to show a circle on average peak points like (10%) is it possible to add circle to the charts after the charts is draw?

- can i add circle to the existing chart in nvd3?
- is it possible to draw another chart on the existing chart to meet this requirement in nvd3?

Comment: i think this might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122915/d3-difference-between-basis-and-linear-interpolation-in-svg-line

Comment: i think this might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122915/d3-difference-between-basis-and-linear-interpolation-in-svg-line

Comment: no this is not the answer i need to done this in nvd3 not d3.

Comment: have you managed to do this? I have asked [a similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322853/circles-on-nvd3-line-chart) question too.