# d3js - line chart adding `circles` throw errors

Tags: d3.js, drawing, linechart

My goal is making a multiple line of line drawing. It is all working fine other than adding the circles on the curves.

Below is the code snippets. `HTML` and `CSS` also added below. Can anyone please help me to fix this?

```js
window.onload = function () {
  
var datas = [
{"date":20111001,"New York" : 63.4, "San Franscisco" : 62.7, "Austin" : 72.2 },
{"date":20111002,"New York" : 58.0, "San Franscisco" : 59.9, "Austin" : 67.7 },
{"date":20111003,"New York" : 53.3, "San Franscisco" : 59.1, "Austin" : 69.4 },
{"date":20111004,"New York" : 55.7, "San Franscisco" : 58.8, "Austin" : 68.0 },
{"date":20111005,"New York" : 64.2, "San Franscisco" : 58.7, "Austin" : 72.4 },
{"date":20111006,"New York" : 58.8, "San Franscisco" : 57.0, "Austin" : 77.0 },
{"date":20111007,"New York" : 57.9, "San Franscisco" : 56.7, "Austin" : 82.3 },
{"date":20111008,"New York" : 61.8, "San Franscisco" : 56.8, "Austin" : 78.9 },
{"date":20111009,"New York" : 69.3, "San Franscisco" : 56.7, "Austin" : 68.8 },
{"date":20111010,"New York" : 71.2, "San Franscisco" : 60.1, "Austin" : 68.7 }

]

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
      .range(["#FF0000", "#009933" , "#0000FF"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  color.domain(d3.keys(datas[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  datas.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date + "");
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: datas.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });
  

  x.domain(d3.extent(datas, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    // .append("text")
    //   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    //   .attr("y", 6)
    //   .attr("dy", ".71em")
    //   .style("text-anchor", "end")
    //   .text("Temperature (ºF)");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  var path = city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
      
  var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength()];
  
  path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
      
  city.selectAll("circle.line")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("fill", "transparent")
      .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return line(d.values) })
      .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return line(d.values) })
      .attr("r", 3.5);

  // city.append("text")
  //     .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  //     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
  //     .attr("x", 3)
  //     .attr("dy", ".35em")
  //     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: At which position do you want to place the circles?? end?? The problem is with the values you set as cx and cy atttributes of circle.

Comment: I would like to add each lines, path start points

Comment: I want to match like this http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/LG8Qe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
  city.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values
    })
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date)
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.temperature)
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "green")
    .attr("fill", "transparent");
```

**Note:** I have commented the line interpolation, since it is not possible to find the exact point positions in that case. Reference: [points on line in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040297/points-on-line-in-d3-js)

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var datas = [{
      "date": 20111001,
      "New York": 63.4,
      "San Franscisco": 62.7,
      "Austin": 72.2
    }, {
      "date": 20111002,
      "New York": 58.0,
      "San Franscisco": 59.9,
      "Austin": 67.7
    }, {
      "date": 20111003,
      "New York": 53.3,
      "San Franscisco": 59.1,
      "Austin": 69.4
    }, {
      "date": 20111004,
      "New York": 55.7,
      "San Franscisco": 58.8,
      "Austin": 68.0
    }, {
      "date": 20111005,
      "New York": 64.2,
      "San Franscisco": 58.7,
      "Austin": 72.4
    }, {
      "date": 20111006,
      "New York": 58.8,
      "San Franscisco": 57.0,
      "Austin": 77.0
    }, {
      "date": 20111007,
      "New York": 57.9,
      "San Franscisco": 56.7,
      "Austin": 82.3
    }, {
      "date": 20111008,
      "New York": 61.8,
      "San Franscisco": 56.8,
      "Austin": 78.9
    }, {
      "date": 20111009,
      "New York": 69.3,
      "San Franscisco": 56.7,
      "Austin": 68.8
    }, {
      "date": 20111010,
      "New York": 71.2,
      "San Franscisco": 60.1,
      "Austin": 68.7
    }

  ]

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 80,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"])
    .range(["#FF0000", "#009933", "#0000FF"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  var line = d3.svg.line()
    //  .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.temperature);
    });

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  color.domain(d3.keys(datas[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key !== "date";
  }));

  datas.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date + "");
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: datas.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: d.date,
          temperature: +d[name]
        };
      })
    };
  });


  x.domain(d3.extent(datas, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) {
      return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
        return v.temperature;
      });
    }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) {
      return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
        return v.temperature;
      });
    })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    // .append("text")
    //   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    //   .attr("y", 6)
    //   .attr("dy", ".71em")
    //   .style("text-anchor", "end")
    //   .text("Temperature (ºF)");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

  var path = city.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return color(d.name);
    });

  var totalLength = [path[0][0].getTotalLength()];

  path
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

  city.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values
    })
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date)
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.temperature)
    })
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("fill", "transparent")
    .attr("stroke", "green")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)

  // city.append("text")
  //     .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  //     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
  //     .attr("x", 3)
  //     .attr("dy", ".35em")
  //     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```